# What are the review requirements regarding QUERY intents?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

Due to hardware restrictions, we are unable to retrieve the current status of many of our lights (their color/brightness/etc.).

In the [QA test cases spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n6iOOX6j42TY-K9UoVG6g-fh5S1DrZ38-1zvEupMwBo/edit#gid=0) found [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/testing-deploying), at the bottom under **Deploying**, a number of QUERY intents are listed to be tested. Does this mean our Smart Home application will not be able to pass certification?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some expectation from the user to know the status of your their house at any time. If you cannot retrieve the state directly from devices, you should be able to use your cloud provider to store a virtual equivalent of the device. Then instead of querying the device directly you can return the state of the virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

If anything, just try to be honest with the review team and they will keep certain limitations in mind.

When submitting for review make sure you provide them with a perfectly working test environment. So if some of your lights don't function like you want them to and you can't get their info, don't provide them for testing.

I'm not familiar with the review process of Smart Home applications but if you provide the review team with the right information of which hardware is and isn't supported I'm sure they won't straight up reject your application for it.